# How to compile in debug mode using maven without making changes to pom.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, veracode

I am trying to run some vulnerability scans(**Veracode**) on a spring boot application. However, the scan provider suggests running the scans with binaries compiled in debug mode using the following in `pom.xml` file.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin> 
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
      <configuration>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

However, we use the same `pom.xml` for production deployment where we don't want debug level jars.

Is there a way to create debug jars by passing some argument to the `mvn` command?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#debug

Comment: Did either of the answers answer your question? If so, could you please acknowledge our help by giving one of us a check? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use profiles.

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>debug</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin> 
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
          <configuration>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profile>
```

Profiles are activated in the `mvn` command, e.g., `mvn ... -Pdebug`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to set the arguments in the command line with `-D` like this:

```sh
mvn compile -Dmaven.compiler.debug=true -Dmaven.compiler.debuglevel=lines,vars,source
```